# How to replace one string to another in sql using PolyLang Wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, replace, polylang

How to replace one string to another one in mysql including language setting ?
Example query for arabic language ( "ar" ) unfortunately it doesnt work :(

```
UPDATE 
`wp_posts` 
SET `post_contant` = REPLACE(`post_content`,'str1','str2') 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
AND ID IN (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, '"ar";i:', -1), ';',1) FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'post_translations');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a small error in your codee, the first from clause is no valid

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET 
    `post_contant` = REPLACE(`post_content`, 'str1', 'str2')
WHERE
    post_status = 'publish'
        AND ID IN (SELECT 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, '"ar";i:', - 1),
                        ';',
                        1)
        FROM
            wp_term_taxonomy
        WHERE
            taxonomy = 'post_translations');
```

Comment: I have corrected my query: UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`,'Surface Area','Surface Area2') WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND ID IN (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, '"ar";i:', -1), ';',1) FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'post_translations'); and now I have this error: #1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a:2:{s:2:"pl"'

Comment: you should alos post a dbfiddle with data, as i really don't kno how description looks like it sees a json, and so you substring_index faisl, but without data,, nobody can help ypu

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that that query returns results not only numbers. So I need only ID numbers. How to remove all values which not are numbers ?

This is part of query used for ID IN () to get all ID numbers:

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, '"ar";i:', -1), ';',1) FROM `wp_term_taxonomy` WHERE `taxonomy` = 'post_translations'